# Jest testing in Javascript - it tests a line, which is not supposed to be tested

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I am new in Jest testing and I created a test for one of my functions in my program. It is used to test the function, which choose the the type of triangle, according to the length of all 3 sides( for example, if the all 3 sides are equal, it returns "Equilateral".

When I run my program, everything is fine, but when I run the test by command "yarn test", it says, that the test is failed, because "ReferenceError: document is not defined in line 2". But in my test function, there is no lines, where the document is mentioned.

This is my function -

```js
const triangleType = (side1, side2, side3) => {
    //check, if exists
    if (
      side1 + side2 <= side3 ||
      side1 + side3 <= side2 ||
      side2 + side3 <= side1
    ) {
      return "Non existing";
    }

    if (side1 === side2 && side2 === side3) {
      return "Equilateral";
    }

    if (side1 === side2 || side1 === side3 || side2 === side3) {
      return "Isosceles";
    }

    return "Scalene";
  };

module.exports = triangleType;
```

And this is my Jest test case -

```js
const triangleType = require('./file');


test('Similar sides to be "Equilateral"', () => {
    expect(triangleType(1,1,1)).toBe("Equilateral")
  })
```

And my console, where the test case happens -

```js
S C:\Users\aannu\Desktop\front end task> yarn test
yarn run v1.22.10
warning package.json: No license field
$ jest
 FAIL  ./file.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    The error below may be caused by using the wrong test environment, see https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string.
    Consider using the "jsdom" test environment.

    ReferenceError: document is not defined

      1 | //defining canvas
    > 2 | const container = document.getElementById("container");
        |                   ^
      3 | const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      4 | const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      5 | let cw = canvas.width,

      at Object.<anonymous> (file.js:2:19)
      at Object.<anonymous> (file.test.js:2:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.869 s
Ran all test suites.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of error messages. Post the error message itself. For example, did you try to go to the link the error message points you to? If you had posted text, I could go there and see what it says but I don't want to type that URL trying to read from one place onto another. Also, notice that it's trying to import `file.test.js` whereas you meant to import `file.js`. When you search your code base, do you not see a file.test.js?

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to text. I tried to do the thing, that is in that link, but nothing happened. I realised, that it tests all the file "file.js" from line 1, not only the function. I moved the function to another file and the test passed. But I don't want to move the function outside my general file. And the file.test.js is the file, that I created. I can't see any other files with name like this.

Comment: Sounds like you have a file that is trying to do too much. I'd advise against having the same file run operations against the DOM and also provide random utilities.

Comment: Thanks! I added "window.onload = function () {}" for the section, where I defined the container, canvas and ctx and now it started to work.

Comment: You're better off creating a function that does the work, putting it in a new file and calling it from somewhere else, they really don't belong in the same file. Especially if you are trying to make your code testable